# Hibernate large collections performance problems despite using 2nd Level Cache

Tags: performance, hibernate, caching, collections

We have a parent object with a collection of 500.000 child objects. We are using Hibernate for mapping with ehcache as the cache provider. Using the 2nd level cache for entities and collection works fine as we can avoid requests to the database.

But loading 500.000 objects by 2nd level cache still produces a lot of cpu and memory garbage and results in a reponse time of a few seconds. As the child objects are not immutable we can't enable the hibernate.cache.use_reference_entries property.

With using an application layer cache of dao objects in top of the hibernate 2nd level cache, there's no cpu and no garbage memory overhead. The response time is a few milliseconds instead of seconds.

But the big disadvantage of this solution is, that we have to manage this cache by ourself. Including invalidation und synchronization in a clustered multithreading system.

My question is, if there's a better solution with the advantages of low cpu and garbage? Does anyone have experience in handling large collections?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that 500k at once?

You could remove the collection from the Parent and query the objects from Child by parent: `SELECT c FROM Child c WHERE c.parent = :parent` and add pagination or filtering when you dont need the 500k at once.

You could also load the data Child entieties as DTO which would improve memory performance because hibernate would not consider these DTO's for dirty checking. I guess this would remove memory footprint by half, although i never benchmarked it. Also a DTO would allow you to omit attributes which you dont need in this certain use case saving memory and CPU.

You could also take a look at [`enableDirtyTracking`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/pc/BytecodeEnhancement.html) in Hibernate 5.